# What is the simplest way to randomise the order of frames in AS3 without repeats?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, random

I have a scene in a flash project where I want the order of the frames to be randomised at run-time. I want each frame to be shown exactly once. I want the duration of each presentation to be constant.

I've been playing around with a couple of David Stiller's suggestions:

- [How to Jump to a Random Frame Label](http://www.quip.net/blog/2006/flash/how-to-jump-random-frame-label)
- [How to Jump Randomly to Frame Labels without Repeats](http://www.quip.net/blog/2007/flash/how-to-jump-randomly-to-frame-labels-without-repeats)

They're a bit outdated (`Void` rather than `void`, `this._totalframes - 1` rather than `MovieClip.totalFrames`), but the principal seems sound.

Still, the approach seems less than optimal. David's examples work really well for a small number of sequences of frames. But I have around 100 individual frames.

What is the best way to do this?

My wishlist:

1. No need to label each frame individually
2. Ideally, no need to repeat code on each frame
3. Easy to change the duration of each frame presention

I'm not experience in Flash, so I be asking for something obviously impossible, but I'd be interested to see suggestions about how best to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without much thought put into it, I would do something like this:

(not tested)

```
//On frame 1 on a clear layer present on all frames. First frame should probably be empty

var frames:Array = [];
for(var i:Number = 1; i<this.totalFrames, i++) {
  frames.push(i+1);
}
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameFunc);
function frameFunc(e:Event) {
  var frameNum:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*frames.length);
  var frame:Number = frames[frameNum];
  frames[frameNum] = frames.pop(); //You could also use splice.
  gotoAndStop(frame);
}

stop();
```

Comment: This looks pretty damn good (not at a PC with flash at the mo). Just by looking at it though, I can see one omission: is there a generally respected way to manage the duration of each frame exposure?

Comment: I guess you could make the event listener into a timer instead. You would also have to check for when the frames-array is empty :)

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question, but there is a very high probability that this solution will show a frame multiple times before showing every frame in a random order.

Comment: How do you figure 32bitkit? I store all the frames that needs to be shown, then delete them from the array as they are picked.

Comment: @JonatanHedborg got it, i see it now. my bad

Comment: This is pretty much spot on. For a full, working example, try this: http://webvm.psych.sussex.ac.uk/research/syn/flashdemos/randomFrame_example.fla